# How do you inject multiple QueryFactory?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, sqlkata

The SqlKata documentation lists the following code:

*.NET 6*

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<QueryFactory>((e) =>
{
    var connection = new SqlConnection(CONST.KenticoConnectionString);
    var compiler = new SqlServerCompiler();

    return new QueryFactory(connection, compiler);
});
```

*HomeController.cs*

```
using SqlKata;
using SqlKata.Execution;

public class HomeController {

    private readonly QueryFactory db;

    public HomeController(QueryFactory db) {

        this.db = db;

    }

    public IActionResult Index() {

        // Here books is of type `IEnumerable<dynamic>`
        var books = db.Query("Books").Where("IsPublished", true).Get();

        // or `IEnumerable<Book>` if using the Generic overload
        var books = db.Query("Books").Where("IsPublished", true).Get<Book>();

        return Ok(books);

    }

}
```

How would I go about using multiple QueryFactory? I have two different databases that I need to query which have separate connection strings.

I can set up multiple QueryFactor within Program / Startup, but I have no idea how to inject the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a factory for `QueryFactory` that will dynamically return you an instance with dynamically injected `ConnectionString`:

```
public class QueryFactoryFactory : IQueryFactoryFactory
{
    public QueryFactory CreateQueryFactory(string connectionString)
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        return new QueryFactory(connection, new SqlServerCompiler());
    }
}

public interface IQueryFactoryFactory
{
    QueryFactory CreateQueryFactory(string connectionString);
}
```

It should be registered in your `ServiceCollection`:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IQueryFactoryFactory, QueryFactoryFactory>();
```

After that, you can inject your factory to the controller and get the needed `QueryFactory` based on the connection string provided you can get from `IConfiguration` (or in any other way):

```
public class HomeController
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IQueryFactoryFactory _factory;

    public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration, IQueryFactoryFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // use the needed connectionString name instead of 'first'
        var books = _factory.CreateQueryFactory(_configuration.GetConnectionString("first"))
            .Query("Books")
            .Where("IsPublished", true)
            .Get();

        return Ok(books);
    }
}
```

It is also possible to create the separate derived class for each of your connection strings and register them in IoC, however, this is a bad approach, to avoid which the factory pattern was invented as well:

```
public class ConcreteQueryFactory1 : QueryFactory
{
    public ConcreteQueryFactory1()
        : base(new SqlConnection("connectionString1"), new SqlServerCompiler())
    {

    }
}

public class ConcreteQueryFactory2 : QueryFactory
{
    public CustomQueryFactory2(IDbConnection connection, Compiler compiler, int timeout = 30)
        : base(connection, compiler, timeout)
    {

    }
}
```

The main benefits of factory over the second approach are:

1. You can change the way objects are created without affecting the rest of your code - **flexibility**;
2. The factory provides a single point for the creation of objects - **encapsulation**;
3. By using a factory, you separate the concerns of object creation from the concerns of object usage - **responsibility separation**;
4. You can easily create mock objects for testing purposes - **testability**.

Comment: Using a derived class was the approach I was working on before you commented. How is a derived class bad practice? What makes a Factory better than using a Derived Class?

Comment: @Magus 1) you can change the way objects are created without affecting the rest of your code - flexibility; 2) the factory provides a single point for the creation of objects - encapsulation; 3) by using a factory, you separate the concerns of object creation from the concerns of boject usage - responsibility separation; 4) you can easily create mock objects for testing purposes - testability. Good question, will update an original answer as well.